# Laravel Hash equivalent in core php

Tags: php, laravel

I already have a web application where i have encrypted all my password using

> Hash::make($string);

What is the equivalent of that in core php , that would help my android developers in syncing with my app. I tried with hash and crypt, it wasn't same. Help me with it, so that it would be easier for my developers to write backend.

Comment: Did you look at the code ? You should be able to answer this question yourself.

Comment: LorenzMeyer well i'm a beginner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using

> password_hash($string);

you can verify it by using

> password_verify($string,$hash);

Hope that helps!!

Comment: Why does this hash function returns different hashes while using the same string?

Comment: @Floris it uses bcrypt, and a new salt is generated every-time - resulting in different hashes for same string.

Comment: Aha that explains a lot. I see that sha1() creates the same hash for the same string. So that's what I need comparing a password on different 2 servers.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that's the `Illuminate\Hashing\BcryptHasher::make()` method. You can check the source of that class to see what's going on:

```
<?php namespace Illuminate\Hashing;

class BcryptHasher implements HasherInterface {

  protected $rounds = 10;

  public function make($value, array $options = array())
  {
    $cost = isset($options['rounds']) ? $options['rounds'] : $this->rounds;

    $hash = password_hash($value, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' => $cost));

    if ($hash === false)
    {
      throw new \RuntimeException("Bcrypt hashing not supported.");
    }

    return $hash;
  }
```

So to do that in core PHP, you'd need to do something like:

```
$string = "some string that needs to be hashed";
$hash = password_hash($string, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' => 10));
```

Comment: Well the previous answer was short and to the point. php manual explains good. Still thankx for the answer