# Encrypt in Laravel 5.7 and Decrypt in Codeigniter 3.1

Tags: php, laravel, codeigniter, encryption

I need to encrypt an string in laravel using `encrypt('string')` helper, **but** should decrypt it in Codeigniter using `$this->load->library('encryption');`. 
When I init Codeigniter encryption i use:

```
$this->encryption->initialize(
        array(
            'driver' => 'openssl',
            'cipher' => 'aes-256',
            'mode' => 'cbc',
            'key' => '11111111111111111111111111111111', // 32-length, same as in Laravel
        )
    );
```

Can someone help with this? I've searched all the internet but nothing, may be someone did this before?

Comment: Can check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24838039/laravel-hash-equivalent-in-core-php

Comment: In vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter.php you can check both encrypt() & decrypt() in Laravel.

Comment: why? just load the laravel class in codeigniter and use that to decrypt.

Comment: @Alex you are right, in this way I solved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing anything about codeigniter here is how I might accomplish this:

1. Install the encryption library from Laravel via composer `composer
   require illuminate/encryption`
2. Create an instance of the Encrypter manually wherever you may need to use it `$encrypter = new \Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter('yourkey');`
3. Perform encryption or decryption with the newly created instance as
   necessary: `$encrypter->encrypt($value);` and `$encrypter->decrypt($value);`
4. Not necessary, but would be helpful, figure out a way to register and access
   Laravel's Encrypter instance from your applications container.